# Change DN openldap

Tags: schema, openldap

I am using InetOrgPerson, organizationalPerson, person and posixaccount objectclasses.

I want the mail attribute to become the RDN/DN so that it can be used for binding (authentications) instead of cn/uid.

How would I do that?

PS: I'm very new to LDAP.

Comment: Using what language? What API?

Comment: If you can, please tag your question with the relevant languages(s), and consider removing "schema" since the question is not directly related to a schema issue.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP API call is `ldap_modrdn()`, it's usually just called `modrdn()` in non-C APIs.

There are two different approaches to the problem you're trying to solve: rather than renaming all your objects the more conventional approach is to use a *search* or *proxy* user to find the DN based on a filter. This hides any naming and hierarchy in the directory.

It goes like this:

1. user types in email & password
2. applications binds to the directory as the limited-access search user
3. search for objects with filter `(mail=whatever)` in the user container(s)
4. if exactly one user is found, then attempt rebind using full DN and user password
5. if success proceed with login

If you search SO for "ldap search authenticate" you should be able to find some suitable code, depending on what you are developing in.